Accessing Shared Assets and Code in Nx Monorepo
To illustrate my question, I have an example Nx project with the following structure:
/nx.json
/tsconfig.base.json
/apps
  /my-app
    /project.json (type application)
    /tsconfig.json
    /src
      /app
        /components
          /comp1
            comp1.component.ts
/libs
  /my-lib
    /tsconfig.json
    /project.json (type library)
    /src
      /index.ts
      /icons
        icon1.svg
        icon2.svg
      /models
        base-models.ts
      /angular
        /components
          comp2
            comp2.component.ts

The goal is to share the assets and code in the my-lib library.
Using Shared Assets
Say I have two components that need to use icons from the shared library, as shown below:
Component 1: apps/my-app/src/app/components/comp1/comp1.component.ts
Component 2: libs/my-lib/src/angular/components/comp2/comp2.component.ts
In the template of each component, I want to include icons, perhaps something like this:
<ion-icon slot="start" src="assets/my-icons/icon1.svg"></ion-icon>

Using Shared Code
I also want to share code from the libs/my-lib/src/models/base-models.ts file, which is exported in libs/my-lib/src/index.ts. For example:
import { BaseModels } from '@monkey/my-lib/models';
Issues
Shared Assets: I tried to configure my-app's project.json to copy the shared assets from the library using the following:
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "libs/my-lib/src/assets",
  "output": "assets"
}

However, after successfully building the project, the assets did not get copied as expected. I noticed some files were in the dist/apps/my-app folder, but not the assets I tried to copy.
Shared Code: I seem to be able to include shared code by including the path to the index.ts in the project tsconfig.json. But I expected to be able to add it (once and only once) in in the tsconfig.base.json, which is extended by the project level tsconfig files... I read somewhere that you may need to add a tsconfig.json at the root, but that seems like a strange thing to do???
I notice that the tsconfig.base.json includes:
"rootDir": ".",
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": { ........ }

while the my-app tsconfig.json includes lines:
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"paths": { ........ }

and project.json lincludes:
  "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-app",

What on earth is going on here? Is the paths in the project overwriting the tsconfig.base.json, rather than "extending" it. That might make sense...
What's the deal with the rootDir and baseUrl???
Questions

How should the two example components access the shared icon icon1.svg correctly using the src="..." path?

How do I properly configure Nx to use shared code from base-models.ts across both the library and app?

My understanding of the nx methodology is that everything that can should go in the shared space. But it's not clear how tsconfig.base.json & the various tsconfig.json files should be structured. In some documentation I've seen, the .base doesn't even exist. It's very confusing...


Notes
I suspect the solution involves configuring various tsconfig files and ensuring the assets are properly handled during the build process.
Any advice on why the assets aren't getting copied correctly would be much appreciated!

I want to post this answer as this topic is hellishly confusing.
1. path resolution
In an nx monorepo, there is a tsconfig.base.json. And for the purposes of clarifying my points, it contains:
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
       "@monkeytronics/shared": ["libs/shared/src/index.ts"],
   },

If you want to follow nx structure, this is the only definition of baseUrl you will need. And you define all of your paths here! With this, you can use your paths in your typsecript imports:
import { monkeySchemas } from '@monkeytronics/shared';
Overwriting baseUrl
If you overwrite baseUrl in an app level tsconfig.json, there will likely be unintended effects. If you are using the paths from tsconfig.base.json, these only work relative to the baseUrl, also defined in tsconfig.base.json. So, if you change it, the paths all break. And unhelpfully, it seems that the angular projects I was bringing into nx all had baseUrl = "./" defined. And that's what was preventing me from pushing my paths back into the root level.
Overwriting paths
The above applies regarding overwriting the baseUrl... Unless you also overwrite your paths. However, be aware that if you overwrite your paths, you must do so completely. While tsconfig.json files use the work "extends", don't be fooled into thinking that you can merge your base paths with the paths object in your tsconfig.json. You can only overwrite the entire object. In any case, if we were to "extend" the paths, the question would arise, which baseUrl would apply. So, in a way, this is cleaner and more robust.
Gotchas
What do you do with a path like this in your app tsconfig.json?
"~/*": ["/*"]

It's app specific, so you can't just move it back into your tsconfig.base.json. My thoughts are that you will need to hunt through your code and remove any such references. They are not compatible with nx structure.
2. Asset Usage
This one is easier. To use shared assets, you do the following in the app level project.json options:
      "outputPath": "dist/apps/my-app",
      {
        "glob": "**/*.svg",
        "input": "libs/shared/src/assets",
        "output": "monkey-shared-svg"
      }

Make sure to correctly define the outputPath. This will pull all the svg files and put them into  dist/apps/my-app/monkey-shared-svg. And they can be accessed from the template as src="monkey-shared-svg/**/*.svg"
Hope this is helpful info.
